# Ruby string with USD "money" converted to number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, currency

Is there currently a gem that's capable of taking strings, all in USD for this purpose, and converting them to a number? Some examples would be:

- "$7,600" would turn into 7600
- "5500" would turn into 5500

I know on the "5500" example I can just do "5500".to_i, but the spreadsheets being imported aren't consistent and some include commas and dollar signs while others do not. There a decent way of handling this across the board in Ruby?

I've tried something like `money_string.scan(/\d/).join` which seems to be fine, just worried I'll run into edge cases I haven't found yet, such as decimal places.

Answer (score 47):

Why not remove all non-digit characters before calling `.to_i`

Example:

```
"$7,600".gsub(/\D/,'').to_i
```

And for a floating point number:

```
"$7,600.90".gsub(/[^\d\.]/, '').to_f
```

Comment: removes '-' if the amount is negative.

Comment: If you need to account for negatives, then just add '-' to the regular expression in the floating point example above. `"-$7,600.90".gsub(/[^\d\.-]/,'').to_f` or `"-$7,600.90".gsub(/[^\d\.-]/,'').to_i`

Answer (score 11):

You can do:

```
"$100.00".scan(/[.0-9]/).join().to_f
```

or to_i if they're only dollars

Comment: Didn't read the last part of your question. I think this is probably the best choice and it should always work. Using \d is fine too obviously.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the [Money](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) gem

```
Money.parse("$100") == Money.new(10000, "USD")
```

Comment: Since version 6.0.0, `parse` was deprecated from Money and is now part of Monetize https://github.com/RubyMoney/monetize

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Monetize` gem:

```
pry(main)> Monetize.parse("$7,600").to_i
=> 7600
```

https://github.com/RubyMoney/monetize

```
pry(main)> Monetize.parse("$7,600").class
=> Money
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to trim any non-numeric characters with a Ruby [RegEx](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html) object.  Sanitize your inputs to remove anything but numbers to the left of a decimal point, and then parse the numbers-only string as a number.

(And note that, if you're getting actual spreadsheets instead of CSV bunk, there's likely a `value` property you can read that ignores the text displayed on screen.)

Answer (score 0):

```
def dollar_to_number(dollarPrice)
  if dollarPrice
    dollarPrice[1, dollarPrice.length].to_i
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using money-rails gem, you can do the following

```
irb(main):004:0> "$7,600".to_money("USD")
=> #<Money fractional:760000 currency:USD>
irb(main):005:0> "5500".to_money("USD")
=> #<Money fractional:550000 currency:USD>
```