# How to parse through complex currency value from a string Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing

I have to parse through a collection of complex currency value strings.There are certain unique cases that also need to be taken into consideration.

Here are some of them (left: string to parse, right: desired return value):

```
"$1,950,000"          #=> "1950000
"$750,000"            #=> "750000"
"$1,433,000[2]"       #=> "1433000"
"$1.3 million"        #=> "1300000"
"$2.183 million[4]"   #=> "2183000"
"US$1,644,736 (est.)" #=> "1644736"
```

I could split the string and then use conditional statement logic for every special case but I am wondering if there is a more "abstract" way to parse through these strings.

**update**

I checked out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20484084/ruby-string-with-usd-money-converted-to-number) which has some good explanation however the "million" part misses. See, if the string is "$1.2 million" I know that after the "." I need a total of 6 digits (or string digits in this case) therefore 4 zero will be added. If I have "$2.183 million" I know that i'll need to add 3 zeros so that there is a total of 6 digits after the "."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to extract the unit like `million`:

```
s = '"$1,950,000"          #=> "1950000
"$750,000"            #=> "750000"
"$1,433,000[2]"       #=> "1433000"
"$1.3 million"        #=> "1300000"
"$2.183 million[4]"   #=> "2183000"
"US$1,644,736 (est.)" #=> "1644736"'

s.scan(/[\$£](\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d*)?)( hundred| thousand| million| billion)?/).each do |m|
  number = m[0].gsub(',', '').to_f
  unit = m[3]
  multiplier = 1

  if unit == ' hundred' then
    multiplier = 1e2
  elsif unit == ' thousand' then
    multiplier = 1e3
  elsif unit == ' million' then
    multiplier = 1e6
  elsif unit == ' billion' then
    multiplier = 1e9
  end

  puts number * multiplier
end
```

prints

```
1950000.0
750000.0
1433000.0
1300000.0
2183000.0
1644736.0
```

Comment: @rararake, Iterate over the list like `s.each { |s2| s2.scan ... }`?

Comment: here's a good tool: https://regex101.com/r/rB1rH7/1, let me know if you need more explanation

Comment: see my updated answer. it does not handle currency conversion, and still just extract the number.

Comment: Great! one last thing, it doesn't work for `"$55 million[1]"` i get `55.0` back instead of `55000000`